# how to get the average of dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
                    A        B
DATE                 
2013-05-01        473077    71333
2013-05-02         35131    62441
2013-05-03           727    27381
2013-05-04           481     1206
2013-05-05           226     1733
2013-05-06           NaN     4064
2013-05-07           NaN    41151
2013-05-08           NaN     8144
2013-05-09           NaN       23
2013-05-10           NaN       10
```

say i have the dataframe above.  what is the easiest way to get a series with the same index which is the average of the columns A and B?  the average needs to ignore NaN values. the twist is that this solution needs to be flexible to the addition of new columns to the dataframe.

the closest i have come was

```
df.sum(axis=1) / len(df.columns)
```

however, this does not seem to ignore the NaN values

(note:  i am still a bit new to the pandas library, so i'm guessing there's an obvious way to do this that my limited brain is simply not seeing)

Comment: READ http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply using `df.mean()` will Do The Right Thing(tm) with respect to NaNs:

```
>>> df
                 A      B
DATE                     
2013-05-01  473077  71333
2013-05-02   35131  62441
2013-05-03     727  27381
2013-05-04     481   1206
2013-05-05     226   1733
2013-05-06     NaN   4064
2013-05-07     NaN  41151
2013-05-08     NaN   8144
2013-05-09     NaN     23
2013-05-10     NaN     10
>>> df.mean(axis=1)
DATE
2013-05-01    272205.0
2013-05-02     48786.0
2013-05-03     14054.0
2013-05-04       843.5
2013-05-05       979.5
2013-05-06      4064.0
2013-05-07     41151.0
2013-05-08      8144.0
2013-05-09        23.0
2013-05-10        10.0
dtype: float64
```

You can use `df[["A", "B"]].mean(axis=1)` if there are other columns to ignore.

Comment: i had to do df.mean(axis=1) to get it right, but thanks for putting me on the right track.   i think i need two or three more coffees this morning. :)

Comment: @zaphod: huh?  That's what I wrote above.  [Oh, you mean in the first line, not in the example.  There I was talking about the behaviour of `df.mean` w.r.t. NaNs, but I can see how that would be confusing.]

Comment: But doesn't mean() calculate the median? That is not the same as average.