# Obtaining the mean value of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I'm trying to obtain the average of every column in my DataFrame using the Pandas module. The image shows an example of the data I'm working with.

Only the index '3 to end' are relevant for the calculation.

I tried using the example given here:
[how to get the average of dataframe column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689514/how-to-get-the-average-of-dataframe-column-values)

However, as a result I get:

```
In: concatenated_df.mean(axis=0)
Out: Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Can anyone maybe shed some light on the situation?

Thanks in advance!

[concatenated_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZllIb.png)

My code to concatenate the files:

```
# appending the signal column of every csv file into a single matrix
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os


path =r'mypath' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))


df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f,delim_whitespace=0,  usecols=[1]) for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)

concatenated_df

# save concatenated_df to .csv
concatenated_df.to_csv
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I provided the code to concatenate the files. In the image 'concatenated_df'.. you can see the output.

From every column I wish to obtain the mean value.

Is there any more info I could provide?

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. Please read that link, and perhaps [ask] as well. Might as well check out [help].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I will be sure to read them carefully. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need filter out first 3 rows by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then get `mean`:

```
s = concatenated_df.iloc[3:].mean()
```

Or is possible filter out first 3 rows by parameter `skiprows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f,delim_whitespace=0, usecols=[1], skiprows=[1,2,3]) 
                     for f in all_files)
concatenated_df  = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)

s = concatenated_df.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you!!

The 2nd option worked, the 1st one unfortunately not, still get:
     Series([], dtype: float64)

Nonetheless, many thanks!